# Uploading jpeg file from webcam.js to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, webcam.js

I have called snap function of `webcam.js` library.I got image data_uri in `base64` format. I want to upload that file to nodejs server. I have called `webcam.upload()` function, I am getting an empty object in `request.body`.
client side code looks like this.

```
 Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
        Webcam.on( 'uploadProgress', function(progress) {
            // Upload in progress
            console.log(progress);
            // 'progress' will be between 0.0 and 1.0
        } );

        Webcam.on( 'uploadComplete', function(code, text) {
            // Upload complete!
            // 'code' will be the HTTP response code from the server, e.g. 200
            console.log(code);
            // 'text' will be the raw response content
            console.log(text);
        } );

        Webcam.upload( data_uri, '/image' );
    } )
```

Server side code looks like this.

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post("/image", function(request, response) {
console.log(request.body);
response.send("OK");
 });
```

Comment: Assuming you're using Express, have you included body-parser?

Comment: Yes, body-parser is included.

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions  use json parser and send data in json format `webcam.upload({data : datauri },'/image');`  But check whether object sending is allowed in webcam.js

Comment: `webcam.upload({data : datauri },'/image');` This is not allowed in webcamjs. Could you please help out with the solution.